# What is the return type of HGETALL in Lua

Tags: lua, redis

I'm writing a Lua script and here's my script :

```
local session = redis.call('HGETALL', accessToken)
if (session == nil) then
  redis.log(redis.LOG_WARNING, 'Session not found : ' .. accessToken)
  return
end
```

I tried multiple if conditions and I cannot find out how to properly validate if the value is null. Also, I don't want the overhead of calling the EXISTS command before.

I tried calling it via telnet and the response from redis is ***0**

Here's the list I tried :

```
if (session == nil) then    
if (session == '[]') then
if (session == '{}') then
if (session == '*0') then
if (session == '') then
if (session == '(empty list or set)') then
if (not session) then
```

None of these conditions are working. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is the result an empty table? Can you check that `session[1] == nil`?

Comment: Sir, you've got the answer!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some quick searching online seems to suggest that the result from `HGETALL` (and other functions which return key/value pairs) is a table of sequential key/value pairs. So `{"key1", "val1", "key2", "val2"}`.

This would indicate that the empty result (given that it isn't `nil`) would be an empty table (i.e. `session[1] == nil`).

Answer (score 0):

A more general way, which also apply for tables with string keys is `next(table_name) == nil`

Your script will be:

```
local session = redis.call('HGETALL', accessToken)
if next(session) == nil then
    redis.log(redis.LOG_WARNING, 'Session not found : ' .. accessToken)
    return
end
```

Of course, in the general case it might be better to also check for nil table `table_name == nil or next(table_nil)`

Comment: And to complete this, here is another question about using the output of redis.call as a dictionary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313598/lua-script-to-return-efficient-dictionary-from-redis-hgetall-call