# Lua script to return efficient dictionary from Redis HGETALL call

Tags: lua, redis, lua-table

I need to use Redis `HMGET` from a Lua script and extract specific values in following code.
But `redis.call('HMGET', table_key, hkey1, hkey2, ...)` return a flat array of `{hkey1, val1, hkey2, val2, ...}`

To extract values by key I wrote:

```
local function flat_map_get(flat_map, hash_key)
    local i = 1
    while flat_map[i] do
        if flat_map[i] == hash_key then
            return flat_map[i+1]
        end
        i = i+2
    end
end
```

Of course, as usage grow, multiple calls to this function presented major performance drop.

**What is an efficient way to read values from the flat array returned by `HMGET`?
Or otherwise, to convert the returned value into a proper key-value table?**

Answer (score 15):

After some profiling and tests, we found the following function to have good performance and use it to get a proper table.

This save the need to call a getter function for each hash key retrieval.

```
local function hgetall(hash_key)
    local flat_map = redis.call('HGETALL', hash_key)
    local result = {}
    for i = 1, #flat_map, 2 do
        result[flat_map[i]] = flat_map[i + 1]
    end
    return result
end
```